# Fazer requisição ao voltar à cena anterior em react-native

Tags: react-native

Estou usando `react-native-router-flux` para as rotas e cenas.

Tenho as cenas A e B, na tela A faço uma requisição `GET` em uma API na função `componentWillMount()` e exibo as informações. Na tela B tenho um form e um botão para salvar e voltar para a cena A usando `Actions.pop()`. Gostaria que, ao voltar para cena A, fosse feito uma nova requisição `GET` para a API para trazer as novas informações.

Tentei usar `Actions.pop()` e `Actions.refresh()`, fiz vários outros testes e não obtive sucesso. Vi em outro post uma sugestão de passar a função que faz a requisição via props para a cena B e executá-la antes de voltar para a cena A, mas também não deu certo. Esta última me pareceu a melhor solução.

Gostaria de saber uma forma de resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi este problema passando uma props para a cena A na função Actions.pop() da cena B, e na cena A implementei o método componentWillReceiveProps() para fazer a chamada na API se receber uma props.

Ficou assim:

**Cena A**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps !== this.props) {
    this.getData();
  }
}
```

**Cena B**

```
Actions.pop({ refresh: {update: true} });
```